# oracle SQL — Replace comma separated string with another set of values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table:

```
B_ID    I_ID    R_ID
W00001  1234    1235,1237
B00001  1235    1236,1235
T00001  1236    1235,1235,1235
X00001  1237    1234,1236,1238
M00001  1238    1238
```

I need output like below using sql

```
B_ID    I_ID    R_ID
W00001  1234    B00001|X00001
B00001  1235    T00001|B00001
T00001  1236    B00001
X00001  1237    W00001|T00001|M00001
M00001  1238    M00001
```

1. R_ID should match its value with I_ID and pick the corresponding B_ID.
2. Commas present in R_ID column should replaced with '|' delimiter.

Example: 1st row R_ID has values 1235,1237. 1235 and 1237 is present in I_ID so their corresponding B_ID is picked i.e B00001,X00001 and expected output is B00001|X00001

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without duplicates and does not rely on any magic numbers:

## Option 1: Hierarchical Query

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data ( b_id, i_id, r_id ) as
select 'W00001', 1234, '1235,1237'      from dual union all
select 'B00001', 1235, '1236,1235'      from dual union all
select 'T00001', 1236, '1235,1235,1235' from dual union all
select 'X00001', 1237, '1234,1236,1238' from dual union all
select 'M00001', 1238, '1238'           from dual;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT b_id,
       i_id,
       ( SELECT LISTAGG( t.b_id, '|' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM )
         FROM   TABLE( CAST( MULTISET(
                  SELECT DISTINCT
                         TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( d.r_id, '\d+', 1, LEVEL ) )
                  FROM   DUAL
                  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( d.r_id, '\d+' )
                ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST ) ) v
                INNER JOIN test_data t
                ON (v.COLUMN_VALUE = t.i_id) ) AS r_id
FROM   test_data d;
```

**Explanation**

The inner correlated select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( d.r_id, '\d+', 1, LEVEL ) )
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( d.r_id, '\d+' )
```

Takes the `r_id` for a single row and and separates it into one row per comma-delimited value; the `DISTINCT` clause means only unique values are output.

This is converted into a table collection expression using `TABLE( CAST( MULTISET( ... ) AS collection_type ) )` so that it can be joined to another table.

This is then self-joined back to `test_data` to convert from displaying `i_id`s to `b_id`s and `LISTAGG()` is used to re-aggregate the multiple rows back to a single row.

**Output**:

```
B_ID         I_ID R_ID
------ ---------- --------------------
W00001       1234 B00001|X00001
B00001       1235 T00001|B00001
T00001       1236 B00001
X00001       1237 W00001|T00001|M00001
M00001       1238 M00001
```

## Option 2: Using PL/SQL

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE numberlist IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_Number_List(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN numberlist DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_result       numberlist := numberlist();
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start ) );
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 ) );
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_result;
END;
/
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT b_id,
       i_id,
       ( SELECT LISTAGG( t.b_id, '|' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM )
         FROM   TABLE( SET( split_Number_List( d.r_id ) ) ) v
                INNER JOIN test_data t
                ON (v.COLUMN_VALUE = t.i_id) ) AS r_id
FROM   test_data d;
```

*(Same output as above)*

**Option 3**:

```
SELECT b_id,
       i_id,
       ( SELECT LISTAGG( t.b_id, '|' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM )
         FROM   test_data t
         WHERE  ',' || d.r_id || ',' LIKE '%,' || t.i_id || ',%'  ) AS r_id
FROM   test_data d;
```

You can improve performance of this option by using a function-based on `',' || r_id || ','` and on `'%,' || i_id || ',%'`.

*(Same output as above)*

Comment: Using connect by level this way will create numerous duplicate rows. You eliminate them with select distinct, but this will result in very poor performance if you had, say, 100000 rows in the input. You need to add a prior clause to the connect by condition.

Comment: @mathguy Adding a `PRIOR` clause to the connect by assumes that the values in the list are ordered. This makes no assumptions as to the order of the values (in fact you can see from the sample data that it is not ordered). You could also solve it using the `SET()` collection operator (rather than `DISTINCT`) but then you need to specify a UDT rather than `SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST`.

Comment: OK, I will add the proper way to do this to my answer, since apparently it is not widely known or understood. `PRIOR` in this type of problem does not require ordering; each row in the base table is ONLY connected to itself. (And then you need one more condition, to break the cycle.)

Comment: @mathguy Using `CONNECT BY LEVEL` in the way I am doing will not create duplicate rows **unless** they already exist in the data and there is no need of using `SYS_GUID()`. What you are talking about is using it with multiple input rows which is **not** the case here as the `DUAL` table only has a single row so there is no risk of cross connecting different rows.

Comment: OK, I keep reading your query and realizing you are right - your query did not duplicate rows.

Comment: However, having to perform a join for every row in the input table seems excessive. For my own information I will compare execution plans - the OP should do the same on his actual data.

Comment: @mathguy Added another option that does not rely on hierarchical queries.

Comment: @MT0 Can you please explain me Option 1 -"nested table" method you have used

Comment: @Rose Explanation and added an Option 3.

Answer (score 0):

In the solution below, I use a standard technique to split each comma-separated string into components (tokens) in factored subquery `prep`. Then I join back to the original table to replace each token (which is an `i_id`) with the corresponding `b_id`, and then put the tokens back together into pipe-separated strings with `listagg()`.

**Note**: This solution assumes that each `r_id` has fewer than 100 tokens (see the "magic number" 100 in the definition of `idx`). If it is known that each `r_id` will have no more than 9 tokens, then 100 can be changed to 10 (resulting in faster processing). If NO upper bound is known beforehand, you can change 100 to some ridiculously large number; 4000 will do if `r_id` is anything but a CLOB, as VARCHAR2 and such have a limit of 4000 characters.

Thanks to MT0 for reminding me to add this note.

```
with test_data ( b_id, i_id, r_id ) as (
       select 'W00001', 1234, '1235,1237'      from dual union all
       select 'B00001', 1235, '1236,1235'      from dual union all
       select 'T00001', 1236, '1235,1235,1235' from dual union all
       select 'X00001', 1237, '1234,1236,1238' from dual union all
       select 'M00001', 1238, '1238'           from dual
     ),
     idx ( n ) as (
       select level from dual connect by level < 100
     ),
     prep ( b_id, i_id, n, token ) as (
       select t.b_id, t.i_id, i.n,
                regexp_substr(t.r_id, '([^,]+)', 1, i.n, null, 1)
       from   test_data t join idx i
                          on i.n <= regexp_count(t.r_id, ',') + 1
     )
select p.b_id, p.i_id, 
       listagg(t.b_id, '|') within group (order by p.n) as r_id
from   prep p join test_data t
              on p.token = t.i_id
group by p.b_id, p.i_id
order by p.i_id;



B_ID         I_ID R_ID
------ ---------- ------------------------------
W00001       1234 B00001|X00001
B00001       1235 T00001|B00001
T00001       1236 B00001|B00001|B00001
X00001       1237 W00001|T00001|M00001
M00001       1238 M00001
```

**Added information** based on further conversation with MT0.

*I edited this "Added information" again based on even more conversation with MT0. Thank you MT0 for keeping me on my toes!*

In the solution below I do away with the magic number 100 and instead I use a common technique to deal with multiple input rows and `connect by level` from dual. I also show a common technique for dealing with duplicates (in the tokens obtained from the comma-separated input strings).

**Query**:

```
with 
     test_data ( b_id, i_id, r_id ) as (
           select 'W00001', 1234, '1235,1237'      from dual union all
           select 'B00001', 1235, '1236,1235'      from dual union all
           select 'T00001', 1236, '1235,1235,1235' from dual union all
           select 'X00001', 1237, '1234,1236,1238' from dual union all
           select 'M00001', 1238, '1238'           from dual
         ),
     prep ( b_id, i_id, n, token ) as (
       select b_id, i_id, level,
                regexp_substr(r_id, '([^,]+)', 1, level, null, 1)
       from   test_data t
       connect by level <= regexp_count(r_id, ',') + 1
              and prior r_id = r_id             -- to only generate the rows needed
              and prior sys_guid() is not null  -- this is unique, to avoid cycles
     ),
     z ( b_id, i_id, n, token, rn ) as (
       select b_id, i_id, n, token,
              row_number() over (partition by i_id, token order by n)
       from prep
     )
select z.b_id, z.i_id, 
       listagg(t.b_id, '|') within group (order by z.n) as r_id
from   z join test_data t
              on z.token = t.i_id
where  z.rn = 1
group by z.b_id, z.i_id
order by i_id;
```

**Result**:

```
B_ID         I_ID R_ID
------ ---------- ------------------------------
W00001       1234 B00001|X00001
B00001       1235 T00001|B00001
T00001       1236 B00001
X00001       1237 W00001|T00001|M00001
M00001       1238 M00001

5 rows selected.
```

Comment: Can you also help me eliminate the duplicates present in R_ID.                     T00001       1236 B00001|B00001|B00001 to      T00001       1236 B00001

Comment: `SYS_GUID()` is used the `CONNECT BY` clause is to prevent cyclic connections [caused by multiple input rows](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2526535). Using a correlated `TABLE` collection expression prevents this as there is only a single input row and the `SYS_GUID()` hack is unnecessary.

Comment: The use of `sys_guid()` is indeed a hack, but so is `connect by level` from `dual` to generate rows in the first place. Both work (for now - until Oracle will make them not work).

Comment: If I execute the above query with the actual data which has more than 9000 records it takes lot of time for execution..can u suggest anything that can increase the performance??

Comment: Is there an index on I_ID? Also: You may want to open a new question (right here on stackoverflow); you may link back to this thread to state the problem and the solutions, which work but take a long time, and ask for help on improving performance. If you do that, make sure to post explain plans (or better yet, execution plans) for what you have tried. I'll give it some thought today too, I will write back if I can come up with anything. But do check about an index on I_ID first, if there isn't one yet that may help.

Comment: By the way, what is "a lot of time"? Perhaps the time is reasonable given the size of your data and the requirement. It would help also if you explained what you expected the execution time to be.

Comment: One more question... by 9000 records I assume you mean rows (input strings). In your actual data, does each row (string) have up to three "tokens" or can there be 10 or 20 "tokens" (aggregated I_ID's) in each string? That will make a huge difference.

Comment: Some rows have oly 2 tokens others have more.Wen i did my analysis I found that maximum token present is around 200 :( that s the reason it's taking time( more than one hr)

Comment: OK. I just did some testing. I created a table with 9000 rows and three tokens per row. I used the query to populate a new table, `results`, through a `create table as select ...` The CTAS statement ran in 1.4 seconds. Then I re-created the table with 9000 rows and 20 tokens per row. The CTAS takes 16 seconds. I will try with 200 tokens, first without an index on I_ID and then I will build an index and try again. This is all done on a cheap laptop with the free (memory-limited) version of Oracle 11.2. I will write back with more test results.

Comment: @Rose - OK, did some more testing. Indexing doesn't help (I don't know what I was thinking - it can't help, since we join to an inline view). I will post the results and the winning query in a new answer to this question, since the "winning query" uses a different method - a recursive factored subquery (recursive CTE).

Answer (score 0):

Decided to add another answer since it uses an entirely different method - the recursive subquery factoring, available since Oracle version 11.2.

I did some testing, with an input (persistent) table called `test_data` with 9000 rows, each r_id being a comma-separated string of 200 tokens; structure very similar to the OP's small sample in the original post. I tried three methods: the hierarchical query (using `connect by` with the `prior sys_guid()` trick), which I proposed; the solution based on a correlated subquery and nested table, posted by MT0; and the recursive query I will show below. In each case, I used the query as the `select...` portion of a CTAS statement.

- The hierarchical query took 39 minutes to complete.
- The correlated subquery and nested table method took 18 minutes.
- The recursive subquery factoring method took 13 minutes.

(To compare apples to apples I modified MT0's query, removing the extra information that the "tokens" in r_id are numbers - I treated them as strings, as do the other two methods.)

Recursive query:

```
with
     prep ( b_id, i_id, str, n, st_pos, end_pos, token) as (
       select  b_id, i_id, ',' || r_id || ',', -1, null, 1, null
         from  test_data
       union all
       select  b_id, i_id, str, n+1, end_pos + 1, instr(str, ',', 1, n+3),
               substr(str, st_pos, end_pos - st_pos)
         from  prep
         where end_pos != 0
     ),
     z ( b_id, i_id, n, token, rn ) as (
       select b_id, i_id, n, token,
              row_number() over (partition by i_id, token order by n)
       from prep
     )
select z.b_id, z.i_id, 
       listagg(t.b_id, '|') within group (order by z.n) as r_id
from   z join test_data t
              on z.token = t.i_id
where  z.rn = 1
group by z.b_id, z.i_id
;
```

Actually one can squeeze a little bit of extra performance; in the anchor part of the recursive CTE (the first member of the `union all` in the definition of `prep`), I could start from `n = 0`, `st_pos = 1` and `end_pos =` the position of the first comma (actually the second in comma in the altered string; I find it a lot easier to add commas at the beginning and the end of the input CSV string and write the recursive CTE as I did.) However, this saves just one iteration out of 200 for each string; so a 0.5% of execution time could be saved. I find the way I wrote the recursive CTE easier to follow.

For completeness, here is the modified version of the "nested table" method I used (credit @MT0):

```
select b_id,
       i_id,
       ( select listagg(t.b_id, '|') within group (order by rownum)
         from   table ( 
                        cast ( 
                               multiset (
                                  select distinct regexp_substr(d.r_id, '[^,]+', 1, level) 
                                  from dual
                                  connect by level <= regexp_count(d.r_id, ',') + 1
                               ) 
                               as sys.odcivarchar2list
                        ) 
                ) v
                inner join test_data t
                on (v.column_value = t.i_id)
       )
from   test_data d;
```

Comment: Wow ....this works fine (y) ...I'm new to SQL..Can you please explain me the "nested table" method you have used

Comment: I was hoping to make it very clear that the "nested table" method is not mine; it is the solution MT0 suggested. You may want to ask him directly.

Comment: @MT0  Can you please explain me the "nested table" method you have used